# How to completely delete list items from memory

Tags: python, list, memory, global-variables

I need a way to completely delete list items from memory.
The point is that even if an object is in more than one list, when I delete it it will no longer be available in any list and it will be completely deleted from memory.
I tried del, but it doesn't work:

```
a = [Object(), Object()]
b = a[1]
del a[1]
```

but the value of a [1] is still in memory and b != None

How do I delete it completely from memory?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What are you expecting to happen to the other references to that object?

Comment: if you assigned to some other variable, you cannot

Comment: This is not how Python works. In Python you have references to objects. You create them (for example) when you use `=` and `del` will delete them. If there is no reference to an object anymore the garbage collector will remove the object, eventually. This is the way you dispose objects.

Comment: As an addition: in some cases the [weakref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html) module is helpful to allow objects to be disposed while there is still a way to reference them.

Answer (score -1):

In Python, assignment operator binds the result of the right-hand side expression to the name from the left-hand side expression.

So when you define this

```
a = [Object(), Object()]
b = a[1]
del a[1]
```

a is an object and the b is another object. When you are defining `b = a[1]` it gives the same reference since the values are the same. but when you are deleting the a[1] simply it disconnect the connection between the a[1] and the value. but still, b is connected to that value so it remains.

[image]

[Link that visualizes evverything](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a%20%3D%20%5B3,4%5D%0Ab%20%3D%20a%5B1%5D%0Aa%5B1%5D%3D5%0Adel%20a%5B1%5D&cumulative=false&curInstr=4&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Comment: *"When you are defining `b = a[1]` it's a new object"* – What? That sounds wrong. Cannot tell if it's badly expressed or factually false. Overall, I don't know how this answers the question.

Comment: a [1] and b are two references to the same object. You can check it, a change in a [1] will affect b, and a change in b will affect a [1].

Comment: The problem is, when I use the function del, it only deletes the reference to the object, not the actual object

Comment: @ParanoidAndroid It's not changing the value! when I defined like that and change a[0] value it's not changing the value of b. have a lokk at it on the url . Ihave edited my answer

Comment: @Sathiyakugan if you change a property of the object, it will effect all the pointers